# Cannot implicitly convert string to text box

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am getting the following failure message when i build on the below two lines

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/][img]http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/eb92ef98ac.jpg

[image]

Exceptions = message.Substring(trav + 1, expdiff - 1);
                    ExceptionList.Add(Exceptions);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Exceptions.Text = message.Substring(trav + 1, expdiff - 1);
ExceptionList.Add(Exceptions.Text);
```

Comment: The TextBox has also the function AppendText() if you don't want to set the whole text completely new and you need to avoid flickering.

Answer (score 0):

seems like `Exceptions` is the name of a `TextBox`, and not a `string`.

Try using the `Exceptions.Text` property in both places that you currently have `Exceptions`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Textbox.Text property